# In AOSP, where is the code that manages mobile handovers?

Tags: android, mobile, android-source, telecommunication

I'm working with AOSP in the context of quality measurements. Right now, I've spent a full day digging and searching where Android manages its mobile connections. Unfortunately with no success...

Can someone point me which class or code section AOSP manages its mobile (GSM, UMTS, LTE) handovers?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Mobile handovers are handled between the mobile networks and the protocol stack in the Android device.  This is all done at a lower level than the Android operating system.

Handover is specified by 3GPP in several GSM/UMTS/LTE specs, found [here.](http://www.3gpp.org/specifications/specification-numbering)